# Login doesn't work with another backend

Tags: python, django, api, twitter-oauth, backend

I wrote a Twitter backend for Django, and a wrapper around the Twitter API to make the "Sign in with Twitter" happen, and everything is working fine, the TwitterUser get's created also the User gets created, in the end after it's authenticated it redirect me to main page but there it doesn't sign in the twitter user.
When I print `request.user` it is AnonymousUser

TwitterUser model

```
class TwitterUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    oauth_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    oauth_secret = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

The backend

```
class TwitterBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, token=None, secret=None):
       if token and secret and username:
            try:
                user = TwitterUser.objects.get(username=username)

                # Econde
                token = token.encode("utf-8")
                secret = secret.encode("utf-8")

                user_oauth_token = user.oauth_token.encode("utf-8")
                user_oauth_secret = user.oauth_secret.encode("utf-8")
                if (bcrypt.hashpw(token, user_oauth_token) == user_oauth_token and
                    bcrypt.hashpw(secret, user_oauth_secret) == user_oauth_secret):
                    return user
                else:
                    return None
            except TwitterUser.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            user = TwitterUser.objects.get(username=username)
            return user
        except TwitterUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The view where login happens

```
def convert_to_access_token(request):
    token = request.GET["oauth_token"]
    verifier = request.GET["oauth_verifier"]

    oauth_token, oauth_secret, user_id, username = twitter.get_access_token(token, verifier)

    tw_user = authenticate(username=username, 
                        token=oauth_token, 
                        secret=oauth_secret)
    if tw_user is not None:
        login(request, tw_user)
        print "authenticated!"
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        oauth_token_hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(b"%s" % oauth_token, bcrypt.gensalt())
        oauth_secret_hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(b"%s" % oauth_secret, bcrypt.gensalt())

        generated_pass = User.objects.make_random_password(length=50)

        user = User(username=username, password=generated_pass)
        user.save()
        tw_user = TwitterUser(
                           user=user,
                           twitter_id=user_id, 
                           username=username,
                           oauth_token=oauth_token_hashed,
                           oauth_secret=oauth_secret_hashed)
        tw_user.save()

        tw_user = authenticate(username=username, 
                            token=oauth_token, 
                            secret=oauth_secret)
        login(request, tw_user)
        print "created+authenticated!"
        return redirect("/")
```

And the backend is in the settings file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
                           "myapp.backends.TwitterBackend")
```

Comment: I think before `return redirect("/")`, you have to call `login(tw_user)` and you can import login from `from django.contrib.auth import login`

Comment: `login(request, tw_user)` is called before ` return redirect("/")`

Comment: The docs here: [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) mention the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<<yourApp>>.TwitterPost'`setting when substituting custom `User` objects. Probably in `settings.py` is best place to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your backend has to be of class Modelbackend, and then return the user or None if failed.

example to login using a hash code:

```
class HashAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, hash=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(profile__login_hash=hash)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
        except:
            return None
```

Also, I didn't include the default auth in settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('App.backends.EmailAuthBackend',
                       'App.backends.KioskModelBackend',
                       'App.backends.HashAuthBackend')
```

Comment: I tried inheriting from the ModelBackend class but again it won't log in the user